# Show the mean of a non-negative integer-valued variable is finite

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X \geq 0$ be an non-negative random variable.

Show that if $P(X > kN) \leq p^k$ for any $k \geq 1$ with some fixed $0 < p < 1$ and $N > 0$ , then $E[X] <\infty$.

My idea is to use that $E[X] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(X > n)$.

$$ E[X] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(X > n) \leq \sum_{n=0}^N P(X > n) + \sum_{n=N}^\infty P(X > N) $$

The first term is finite, but I am not sure how to argue the finiteness of the second term. I tried to start with relating the second term with the condition $P(X > kN) \leq p^k$ but didn't seem to go anywhere. i.e.

$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=N}^\infty P(X > N) = \sum_{n=N}^\infty p = \infty \\
\end{align*}$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P\left(\frac XN > k\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P\left(X >N k\right)\leqslant \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p^k<\infty
$$
hence $X/N$ has a finite expectation and so has $X$.

Comment: Thanks Davide. How do you know that $\frac{X}{N}$ is integer-valued? If not, I don't think $E[\frac{X}{N}] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(\frac{X}{N} > k)$ holds.

Comment: I did not claim that $X/Ń$ is integer-valued, neither the equality you mention. I just use the fact that a non-negative random variable $Y$ has a finite expectation if and only if $\sum_k P(Y>k)$ is finite.